# How do I set the ReSharper default Company and Copyright?

Tags: c#, resharper, stylecop

I just installed Stylecop 4.5RC along with ReSharper.  When I create a new class, I see that I am now compliant (yay!), but I want the company to be my company, not Microsoft.  I also have too much to do to have to worry about updating the copyright text.  How do I fill these in by default?

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="ReaderResultTypes.cs" company="Microsoft">
// TODO: Update copyright text.
// </copyright>
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

--

Comment: Isn't this company name related to fields that you fill in AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: What if you are Microsoft.. what then?  :)

Comment: Check out a great tutorial at [http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/automating-file-header-information-with-resharper/](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/12/automating-file-header-information-with-resharper/). It shows how to define header per project or globally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thats looks like the header from StyleCop. (Last version of StyleCop include the StyleCop plugin for resharper)

Ok how to change? Right click on your project in the solution explorer. Select the context menu item "StyleCop settings". On the settings dialog switch to the tab "Company Information" and check the checkbox. Enter your copyright informations in the fields. Done :-)

Comment: Now if I could only change all my projects at once!

Comment: Sure. At first you have to do it for every project. But you can create a settingsfile for all projects. Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sourceanalysis/archive/2008/05/25/sharing-source-analysis-settings-across-projects.aspx

Comment: The header will updated if you are running a resharper cleanup for the file. (Menu->Resharper->Clean up code..)

I have written me a resharper live templated called "fileheader" and its easy to use. I Upload it for you. https://www.zeta-uploader.com/546430139
How to import live templates: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Templates/LiveTemplates/manageLive.html#ImportExport

You can customize the vs-template for filetype, too.

Comment: You should also note that you might have to restart visual studio for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I cannot see 'StyleCop settings' :(