# How to set StyleCop company name and copyright? (VS2019 with R#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop, visual-studio-2019

ReSharper (with StyleCop plugin) helps to generate the header text of each file:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="Car.cs" company="">
//   
// </copyright>
// <summary>
//   Defines the Car type.
// </summary>
// -------------------------------------------------------
```

However, it keeps showing the following warning. Clicking on the suggestion does not fix it.

[image: header text]

How to configure this so it gets auto-filled or at least gets fixed by the ReSharper suggestion.

PS: None of the solutions present in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117066/how-do-i-set-the-resharper-default-company-and-copyright) are working with VS2019.

Comment: Odd, are you sure the company name saved?

Comment: @BugFinder: where?

Comment: You said you tried the items in the link - the style cop settings

Comment: The link does not exist at all in VS2019, hence the question

Comment: I dont have resharper at work, id have to check at home, i thought the stylecop settings were in there

Comment: Well I googled, and got this https://blog.submain.com/stylecop-detailed-guide/ whcih seems to cover specifically 2019, and specifically states generate an XML doc and set the copyright information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to manually add a new file to each project root called `Settings.StyleCop`. You can then add the copyright info and the company name accordingly. ReSharper will be able to place them correctly later on. You can use the same file for any further settings not available directly in the ReSharper options.

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules">
      <AnalyzerSettings>
        <StringProperty Name="CompanyName">PEAK Consulting Services GmbH</StringProperty>
        <StringProperty Name="Copyright">All Rights Reserved ©  2022</StringProperty>
      </AnalyzerSettings>
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```